# Creating draggable panels

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to create a panel which has three child panels which can be dragged to left side only. when they are fully visible( when they are completely appear on the parent panel), the parent panel should be desabled ( I used modal config, but the child panel overlay on one another and they resized to the html content inside them). When three child panels were dragged to the left side, the parent panel should be enabled. User may again drag those child panels right to the initial position, then the parent panel again should be desabled. I could only create the child panels with the sliding effect, but don't know how to acheive other requirements, coz i am new to sencha touch and extjs. Are there any other resources to learn more about sencha and ExtJs?

And other thing is, as an example, Sencha docs dont explain more about Draggable object's 'constraint' ,'direction' ..etc. where can I find more details about Those classed which are not fully described in their docs.

I have attached two images( initial look of the panels and how it should look when child panels are dragged), Can anyone give me few hints how to achieve my task?. Thank you very much!!
[image: This is how it should look, first]

[image: This is how it should look when the child panels are dragged to left.small portion should appear in order to drag them back]